# Is there some error in parsing object using swifty json?

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to parse json to an object but i get this error?

Here's the function:

```
private func unwrap(_ object: Any) -> Any {
    switch object {
    case let json as JSON:
        return unwrap(json.object)
    case let array as [Any]:
        return array.map(unwrap)
    case let dictionary as [String: Any]:
        var unwrappedDic = dictionary
        for (k, v) in dictionary {
            unwrappedDic[k] = unwrap(v)
        }
        return unwrappedDic
    default:
        return object
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f9cbfe0)

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop: `unwrap(_:` calls `unwrap(_:` which calls `unwrap(_:` which calls `unwrap(_:` which calls `unwrap(_:` .... which 

Comment: @vadian, which overflows the stack?

Comment: @user28434 Right, it's a overflow error.